# Generate HTML parsing with tr, how to replace/remove table-rows if not needed?

Tags: c#, html

I need to parse a html template. Part of the Html template looks like below

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>City</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>Country</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<tr>
</table>
```

The above template is then replaced with the user data using C#.

```
if (obj.City == null || obj.City == "Specific Parameter")
{
    strGetBody = strGetBody.Replace("City", "");

}
else
{
    strGetBody = strGetBody.Replace("City", obj.City);

}
```

Below is the template after replacing the generic data to user data

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Abc</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>**&nbsp;**</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>India</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<tr>
</table>
```

I want to parse the tr whose value is null. Is there any possible way to parse the tr element and delete the entire row if the td value is null for that row?

Comment: Why don't you generate the HTML instead of replacing parts?

Comment: Only user data need to be replaced and body of the template is same for all. So the template is the static one

Comment: In your example what is the value of obj.City??

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you generate the HTML instead of replacing parts of it? Here is a possible implementation:

```
StringBuilder rowsBuilder = new StringBuilder();
string row = "<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td></tr>";
if (obj.Name != null)
{
    rowsBuilder.AppendFormat(row, "Name", obj.Name);
}
if (obj.City != null)
{
    rowsBuilder.AppendFormat(row, "City", obj.City);
}
if (obj.Country != null)
{
    rowsBuilder.AppendFormat(row, "Country", obj.Country);
}
string html = string.Format("<table>{0}</table>", rowsBuilder.ToString());
```

It's simpler and more fail-safe than using `String.Replace`.

Comment: By doing this, will it eliminate or hide the tr, if the <td> has null value. because i do not want to see any blank rows in the output

Comment: @user3406037: you've forgotten to add the question mark ;) Yes, it will simply not generate the row so there is no need to hide or remove it.

Comment: I tried applying the above code, but the problem is i have to go with the static template otherwise whole context need to be changed which is not feasible

Comment: @user3406037: then i would make placeholdersfor the complete section including the related row(s). Then you can replace these placeholders with `String.Empty` easily.

Comment: please can you elaborate what rowsBuilder.AppendFormat(row, "Name", obj.Name); line does? ..as i am coming across the error: "input string is not in proper format" if i get some clue then i can change accordingly

Comment: @user3406037: [`AppendFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is working in the similar way as `String.Format`, it allows to parse format-strings. You can add placeholders that are wrapped in curly braces(`{0}`). The number is important since it represents the (zero based) number of parameters. So the first parameter after the format-string replaces `{0}` and the second parameter replaces `{1}`. My code above is working, so look at the format-string(`row`) and the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced  `<tr>` with `<tr style="display:none">` at required conditions which worked amazingly :)

```
 if (obj.City == null || obj.City == "Specific Parameter")
    {
      if(strGetBody.Contains("<tr id=\"city\">"))
        {
        strGetBody = strGetBody.Replace("<tr id=\"city\">", "<tr id=\"city\" style=\"display:none\">");
        }
    }
    else 
    {
       strGetBody = strGetBody.Replace("City", obj.City);

    }
```